# Disjoint Topological Embeddings

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Each canonical injection $\omega_i: X_i \rightarrow \coprod_{i \in I}X_i$ is a topological embedding and an open map.

My attempt:

To proceed, I will identify $X_i$ with $X_i^*= w_i(X_i)$. If $U$ is open in the disjoint union then $w_i^{-1}(U)$ $=$ $U\cap X_i$ is open in $X_i$ for each $i$. Hence it is continuous for each i. Clearly, the function is injective. Hence restricting its codomain to $X_i$ yields the identity map, and since the topologies  of the codomain and domain are the same, the map is a homeomorphism onto its image. If $V$ is open in the codomain then for each i$\in I$   $w_i(V)$ $=$ $V$, which is open. Hence the map is an open topological embedding.

Is my attempt correct? (Please answer this)

Comment: You have not stated what definition of the topology on $\coprod_{i \in I} X_i$ are you working with, so it's a little hard to know what to say.

Comment: A subset $U$ of the disjoint union is open iff its intersection with each $X_i$ is open in $X_i$ (as a subset of the disjoint union)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is formally incorrect, because formally $X_j\not\subseteq \coprod_{i\in I} X_i$. There's lots of hand-waving when you jump between the disjoint union and its members. You talk about "identifying" $X_j$ with its image $X_j^*$ but that's just pretty much restating that $\omega_j$ is a homeomorphism onto image, right?

Either way, this nuance can be resolved if we just go back to definitions:

$$\coprod_{i\in I}X_i=\bigg\{(i,x)\in I\times\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\ \bigg|\ x\in X_i\bigg\}$$

The topology on $\coprod_{i\in I}X_i$ is given as follows: $U\subseteq\coprod_{i\in I}X_i$ is open if for any $i\in I$ the set $\{x\in X_i\ |\ (i,x)\in U\}$ is open in $X_i$.

With that the standard embedding $\omega_j:X_j\to\coprod_{i\in I} X_i$ is simply given by $\omega_j(x)=(j,x)$. It's obviously injective. With this function we can also rewrite our topology: $U\subseteq \coprod_{i\in I}X_i$ is open if and only if for any $j\in I$ the set $\omega_j^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X_j$. And so clearly $\omega_j$ is continuous.

On the other hand $\omega_j$ is an open map. This follows from the simple observation that if $U\subseteq X_j$ is open then so is $\{j\}\times U$ in $\coprod X_i$.

Finally an injective, open and continuous map is a homeomorphism onto image. This follows from the following observation: if $f$ is a bijection then $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}$ is open.

Comment: The book states that identifying it with its image is a convention, and uses the two interchangeably as subsets. The concept of identifying sets with other sets is quite new to me, any thoughts? Furthermore, I still have not reached the section on quotient maps.

Comment: @topologicalmagician such identifications are very common. But before you can use them you have to prove that this actually makes sense. I may be wrong but I think that this is one of those rare cases that it is not valid to do. Either way the formal proof I've presented is definitely free of such nuances.

Comment: I totally agree, but I suppose I am yet not sure when to use the convention and when to not use it. I am not too sure what you mean by "you have to prove that this actually makes sense", because identifying is a matter of convention. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @topologicalmagician what does "to identify" mean? Typically when we say "I identify $X$ with $Y$" we mean that anything said about $X$ (in some context/universe) is also true for $Y$ and vice versa. In the context of topological spaces this translates to "being homeomorphic". Unless by "to identify" you mean something else. I don't like this kind of maths ("to identify"), it is hand-waving.

Comment: By identify, I mean that we treat $X_i$ as a subset of the disjoint union. I agree. It is quite foreign to me and doesn't seem formal.

Comment: Actually, to many learners of mathematics, "identification" comes all too easily. For example, too often one sees a statement like "this group is $\mathbb Z$" instead of the more formally correct "this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$". But it's important to try to learn formal and the informal language and how to pass between them. You can perhaps give yourself a long-term exericise: whenever you see the concept of "identification" invoked, see if you can figure out what kind of isomorphism is intended.

Comment: @topologicalmagician you cannot treat $X_i$ as a subset of the disjoint union, because it is simply not. Unless all $X_i$ are pairwise disjoint, in which case one can argue that the disjoint union and usual union are "the same". But in general the disjoint union contains a "copy" of $X_i$, not $X_i$ itself.

Comment: Please look at introduction to topological manifolds by lee to understand what I mean

Answer (score 0):

The way freakish presents it, is the cleanest: with a concrete "disjointification" of the $X_i$ so that we can distinguish $X_i$ from its topological copy $\{(i,x): x \in X_i\} \subset \coprod_{i \in I} X_i$.

If we ignore that and treat the $X_i$ as really disjoint from the start and the disjoint sum as a normal union and the $\omega_i$ as "identify-embeddings" we can just say that $\omega_i$ is continuous by definition (the disjoint union topology is the *strongest* topology that makes all $\omega_i$ continuous), 1-1-ness is obvious, and openness too: as $U \subseteq X_i$ open (and $X_i$ open in $\coprod_{i \in I} X_i$ as $X_i \cap X_j$ is always open (almost almost empty, except when $i=j$ when it's $X_i$, open in $X_i$ so by definition of the union topology we've shown $X_i \subseteq \coprod_{i \in I} X_i$ is open) so $U$ is open in $\coprod_{i \in I} X_i$ and so $\omega_i$ is an embedding.

So your attempt is incorrect in a formal sense, but is sort of correct in an informal one.

Comment: Haha, I was waiting for your comment :P